# SockJS WebSocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Estou tentando usar o SockJS, e eu coloquei no HEAD do meu index o `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/1/sockjs.min.js"></script>` e o javascript:

```
var wsUrl = 'ws://' + window.location.host 
var ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl + '/aplicacoes/index.html')

ws.onopen = function () {
    console.log('open');
};
ws.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('message', e.data);
};
ws.onclose = function () {
    console.log('close');
};

ws.send('test');
ws.close();
```

E aparecerem 2 erros no meu console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.(…)

E o erro:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://172.36.35.245/aplicacoes/index.html' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Como que eu faço para conectar com o WebSocket?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema? O mesmo está acontecendo comigo :/